# For loop paired to t tests returning matrix error

Tags: r, matrix, vector, t-test

I have a large set of data frames and would like to conduct a series of t-tests between different columns to find significance. Each data frame has identical headers but a different number of rows.

This is my code:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.txt")
for (fileName in fileNames) {
sample <- read.delim(fileName)
print(fileName)
placeholder.1 <- row_t_welch(sample[,c("A284_1", "A284_2")], sample[,c("A285_1", "A285_2") 
}
```

Where fileNames = a list of: chr [1:383], and _1 & _2 are biological replicates

---

My code returns the error:

```
Error in assert_numeric_mat_or_vec(x):
"x" must be a numeric matrix or vector
```

If I type in the name of the files individually the code works but not when using 'sample'

Can anyone help me?
This is an excerpt from one of my files

```
      seq seq_id A284_1 A284_2 A285_1 A285_2 A286_1 A286_2 A287_1 A287_2 A288_1 A288_2 A289_1 A289_2 A290_1 A290_2 A291_1 A291_2   N2_1   N2_2
1  0.0345 0.0025 0.0134 0.0000 0.0114 0.0064 0.0011 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0132 0.0094 0.0076 0.0000 0.0000 0.0023 0.0213 0.0130 0.0101
2  0.0394 0.0049 0.0015 0.0000 0.0011 0.0010 0.0000 0.0000 0.0015 0.0022 0.0013 0.0014 0.0011 0.0009 0.0000 0.0000 0.0021 0.0014 0.0013 0.0007
3  0.0296 0.0074 0.0000 0.0000 0.0008 0.0005 0.0011 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0038 0.0000 0.0000 0.0003 0.0014 0.0050 0.0032
4  0.0197 0.0099 0.0059 0.0015 0.0030 0.0044 0.0011 0.0075 0.0015 0.0022 0.0017 0.0023 0.0022 0.0023 0.0000 0.0054 0.0027 0.0014 0.0022 0.0022
5  0.0099 0.0123 0.0045 0.0046 0.0038 0.0049 0.0076 0.0000 0.0030 0.0067 0.0039 0.0054 0.0039 0.0067 0.0051 0.0054 0.0071 0.0071 0.0060 0.0052
```

Comment: `read.delim()` returns a `data.frame` whereas you require a matrix. Try converting it to a matrix.

Comment: Please don't include images of your data. Include the output from `dput(head(data))` or a simple made-up example that we can copy/paste into R

Comment: Thankyou @anotherfred! It now works. What I did was insert `sample <- data.matrix(sample)` under `sample <- read.delim(fileName)` and `print(placeholder.1)` underneath my statistical test. This was as calling the `placeholder.1` variable returned a null result